# Mean of non zero values in sparse matrix?

Tags: python, scipy, sparse-matrix

I'm trying to calculate the mean of non-zero values in each row of a sparse row matrix. Using the matrix's mean method doesn't do it:

```
>>> from scipy.sparse import csr_matrix
>>> a = csr_matrix([[0, 0, 2], [1, 3, 8]])
>>> a.mean(axis=1)
matrix([[ 0.66666667],
        [ 4.        ]])
```

The following works but is slow for large matrices:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> b = np.zeros(a.shape[0])
>>> for i in range(a.shape[0]):
...    b[i] = a.getrow(i).data.mean()
... 
>>> b
array([ 2.,  4.])
```

Could anyone please tell me if there is a faster method?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This seems the typical problem where you can use `numpy.bincount.` For this I made use of three functions:

```
(x,y,z)=scipy.sparse.find(a)
```

returns rows(`x`),columns(`y`) and values(`z`) of the sparse matrix. For instace, `x` is `array([0, 1, 1, 1].`

`numpy.bincount(x)` returns, for each row number, how meny nonzero elemnts you have.

`numpy.bincount(x,wights=z)` returns, for each row , the sums of non-zero elements.

A final working code:

```
from scipy.sparse import csr_matrix
a = csr_matrix([[0, 0, 2], [1, 3, 8]])

import numpy
import scipy.sparse
(x,y,z)=scipy.sparse.find(a)
countings=numpy.bincount(x)
sums=numpy.bincount(x,weights=z)
averages=sums/countings

print(averages)
```

returns:

```
[ 2.  4.]
```

Answer (score 9):

With a CSR format matrix, you can do this even more easily:

```
sums = a.sum(axis=1).A1
counts = np.diff(a.indptr)
averages = sums / counts
```

Row-sums are directly supported, and the structure of the CSR format means that the difference between successive values in the `indptr` array correspond exactly to the number of nonzero elements in each row.

Comment: best way to avoid division by zero error? I added this before the division: `counts[counts == 0] = 1` but don't know if it is the best choice. Logic is that if counts has a 0 then sums has to be 0 also in that position. Thus if we want to keep it 0, doesn't matter what we divide by.

Answer (score 3):

I always like summing the values over whatever axis you are interested in and dividing by the total of the nonzero elements in the respective row/column.

Like so:

```
sp_arr = csr_matrix([[0, 0, 2], [1, 3, 8]])
col_avg = sp_arr.sum(0) / (sp_arr != 0).sum(0)
row_avg = sp_arr.sum(1) / (sp_arr != 0).sum(1)
print(col_avg)
matrix([[ 1.,  3.,  5.]])
print(row_avg)
matrix([[ 2.],
        [ 4.]])
```

Basically you are summing the total value of all entries along the given axis and dividing by the sum of the `True` entries where the matrix != 0 (which is the number of real entries).

I find this approach less complicated and easier than the other options.

Comment: I like this approach too, upvoted. One improvement is to avoid forming the `x != 0` (which can be large/memory intensive) matrix by using `nnz`.

Answer (score 2):

A simple method to return a list of average value:

```
a.sum(axis=0) / a.getnnz(axis=0)
```

Assume that you don't have any explicit zero in your matrix.
Change the axis if you will.